# SQL Server 2008 R2 strange index usage

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing, filtered-index

I have a question about SQL Server 2008 R2 index usage, specifically filtered index usage. Here is my scenario:

**@@version** output:

- *Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)*
- *Apr  2 2010 15:48:46*
- *Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation*
- *Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)*

Table in question has **52.114.057** records (with primary key Id field). It is consisted of one ID (int) primary key IDFK (int) (unique, foreign key), TypeID (int) field (not primary key!) and multiple custom metadata fields (vcValue001 - vcValue020 for varchar values, dcValue - dcValue020 for number values (decimal sql type) and dtValue001 - dtValue020 for datetime fields).

Simple layout would be:

- ID (int) (primary key)
- IDFK (int) (unique, foreign key) (edited)
- TypeID (int)
- vcValue001 (varchar)
- ...
- vcValue020 (varchar)
- dcValue001 (decimal(38,8))
- ...
- dcValue020 (decimal(38,8))
- dtValue001 (datetime)
- ...
- dtValue020 (datetime)

Distinct TypeID's inside that table is **71**, and the TypeID in question is 131 (number is actually not relevant, it just happens that this is actual number used). For this TypeID=131 there are **27.583.573** records inside a table. Indexes are created on each individual TypeID + ("vc", "dc" and "dt" fields) (that means it has 60 indexes + some other). e.g. index on "TypeID, vcValue001" (since I'm always using TypeID as criteria when constructing query).

Now to the query part:

```
select top 1000 m.IDFK, m.dtValue002 [MyDate]
from dbo.Metadata m
where (m.nTypeID = 131) and
      (m.vcValue001 = 'A') and
      (m.dtValue002 between '20131212' and '20140312 23:59:59') and
      (m.vcValue003 = 'B') and
      (m.vcValue011 = 'C')
order by m.dtValue002 desc, m.IDFK desc
```

I have replaced actual values with A, B and C, only datepart is correct. Counts for separate ranges are following:

- For nFileTypeID = 131 and vcValue001 = 'A': 180
- For nFileTypeID = 131 and dtValue002 range: 1.179.463
- For nFileTypeID = 131 and vcValue003 = 'B': 2.380.090
- For nFileTypeID = 131 and vcValue011 = 'C': 33

For faster performance I've also created filtered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Metadata_nTypeID000131_vcValue001_dtValue002_vcValue003_vcValue005_IDFK ON dbo.Metadata
(
    vcValue001 asc,
    dtValue002 asc
    vcValue003 asc,
    vcValue005 asc,
    IDFK asc
)
WHERE (nTypeID = 131 AND vcValue001 IS NOT NULL AND dtValue002 IS NOT NULL)
```

With my current SQL knowledge the above query should benefit from using filtered index, but unfortunately does not. The strangest part is that if I remove "desc" keyword from "m.IDFK" order by column, then it uses filtered index. I've also tried asc order for both columns (m.dtValue002 and m.IDFK) but it still won't use it. If filtered index is not used, then the query uses index on (nTypeID, dtValue002) resulting in approx. 5.000.000 reads, while when using filtered index I get 17 reads. I also cannot force filtered index with index table hint, because SQL Server won't allow it, although WHERE condition matched condition used in filtered index.

Here is table of "order by" combinations and filtered index usage:

- (m.dtValue002 asc, m.IDFK asc): filtered index NOT USED (5mio reads)
- (m.dtValue002 asc, m.IDFK desc): filtered index USED (17 reads)
- (m.dtValue002 desc, m.IDFK asc): filtered index USED (17 reads)
- (m.dtValue002 desc, m.IDFK desc): filtered index NOT USED (5mio reads)

How it is possible that filtered index is only used when "order by" fields do not match in direction (asc, dec). I've searched for this problem, but have not found any solution to it. I've also tried creating filtered index on all descending order, an alternate order, but no luck. However, I do need both fields be ordered the same way.
Any direction or suggestion would help me a lot.

Just when I think I know some SQL stuff, it's puzzle like this that shakes my knowledge ;)

**EDIT**: If instead of using IDFK I use ID field for sorting, it work OK (e.g. I get a lot less reads and both sorts can be turned into same direction).

P.S.
  I'm new to SO, so if there's something not right with my question, please let me know.

Best regards!

Comment: While not exactly your problem, this site maybe able to help shed some light [http://explainextended.com/2009/04/27/descending-indexes/](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/27/descending-indexes/)

Comment: Solved my own problem ;) I've actually written wrong table structure. Instead of just ID (PK) I also have ID2 (unique, foreign key to another table). When using PK ID I get good performance, but when using ID2 (which is also included in index), I get performance written above. Thank you Jason for above link, it helped to shed some light on the matter. I've also edited question to reflect my problem.

Comment: ...This is a rather problematic table design.  Why was this chosen?  And having that many indices is going to make updating that table **crawl**.  Don't use [BETWEEN with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), especially on SQL Server (or in my opinion, at all).

Comment: Why is this problematic table design? This design was chosen because our customers want to have custom metadata defined and searchable. We've come to this design after EAV design has become too slow on large amount of data. Updates are always on several fields not all of them.

Comment: I've read an article about BETWEEN for dates and I am aware of pitfalls using datetime range values. However in every project we only use datetime (or in newer datetime2). My above SQL is probably wrong for the last second of the last day (betwen ...59.000 and 59.997). Should change that to ".997" or maybe use less than next day (e.g. < '20140313').